# jQuery UI Sortable Connected List - Over event not fired when item is scrolled into new list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Trying to create similar sorting functionality that is comparable to an iPhone. I've noticed that sortable items are not immediately detected by a connected list when the item is "scrolled into" a connected list.

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmxrrjw7/6/). You will notice that the [over event](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-over) is not fired immediately when a sortable item from the first list is scrolled into the second list. You have to first move the mouse around before the event is fired. This becomes an issue when you let go of the mouse before the event is fired, which keeps the item in the first list. Is this a jQuery bug? Is there any sort of work around?

Here is my javaScript:

```
$(function () {
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    over: function () {
        alert("Over");
    },
    start: function () {
        $("#wrapper").animate({
            'scrollLeft': '+=330px'
        });
    },
    scroll: false
}).disableSelection();
```

});

Please note that I do want to use the jquery ui sortable scroll option. The page should scroll to the correct location by itself.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait until your `scroll` animation  and position the `placeholder` in the new `sortable`. Like this:

```
 start: function (e, ui) {
            var cur_helper = ui.placeholder
            $("#wrapper").animate({
                'scrollLeft': '+=330px',

            }, function () {
                //you place it before equivalent position in sortable1
                $('#sortable2 > li').eq(ui.item.index()).before(cur_helper)

            });
        },
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/um9vggb1/2/